# enhance the variety of salad?

Tags: word-choice

> In order to enhance the ........... of salad plate, lay some shaped tomatoes in the center.
>   a. look   
> b. variety  
> c. mood  
> d. occasion

I suppose the right answer is look.

1. What's wrong with variety?
2. The question made me wonder what if I want to talk about different types of ingredient of the salad. For example, I see this salad nicely decorated and it contains a lot of different ingredients.

> The variety of salad amazed me.

Does the sentence above make sense to mean 'I was amazed by different ingredients used in the salad'? If not how should I edit the sentence? Is there a different word to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you've transcribed the question correctly, there's a grammatical error in it. It should be:

> In order to enhance the ........... of *the* salad plate, lay some shaped tomatoes in the center.

Now, with regards to your questions:

> What's wrong with variety?

The clue is in the second half of the sentence. Variety refers to a range of things, and enhancing a variety would be adding more different types of things to that range. However, the verb used is *lay*, which refers to the positioning (and by extension, the look) of the salad plate. If *lay* were swapped with a word like *add*, *variety* would be the correct choice.

> Does the sentence above make sense to mean 'I was amazed by different ingredients used in the salad'? If not how should I edit the sentence? Is there a different word to do that?

As is, I would parse the sentence as you being amazed at the different types of salad available, not the ingredients *within* the salad. There are a few ways to go about changing the sentence. You can be more explicit and mention the ingredients directly:

> The variety of ingredients in the salad amazed me.

You can also be more general by referring to the variety *in* the salad.

> The variety within the salad amazed me.

Comment: Interesting! So if I replace 'lay' with 'add', 'variety' will be correct. Does the meaning of the first part of the sentence change accordingly? What does 'In order to enhance the variety of the salad plate' mean: 1) in order to have more different **kinds of salad plate** or 2) in order to have **a salad plate** with more different ingredients.

Comment: It would be correct, but *enhance* is an odd word to use with variety. It's not wrong per se, but a more natural word to use instead would be *increase*.

Your following question highlights the problem with using *variety* in this sentence. The definition is basically Answer 2, but it's awkwardly worded. The problem is with **variety in the salad plate**. Even with context, it's not immediately obvious what *variety* is referring to. If you were adamant on using "enhance the variety", I would word the sentence as such:

In order to enhance the variety **of ingredients** of the salad plate

Comment: One other comment I'd like to make -- *salad plate* is also a very strange phrase. Salad tends to be served in bowls, and thus you would call it a **salad bowl** or **bowl of salad**. If the salad is indeed on a plate, I would use **plate of salad** over **salad plate**.

Comment: +1 However I still don't get it why by using 'add' in place of 'lay', variety would be correct, too. :-(